# Set SQL browser connection to SSAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, ssas-2012

I am trying to make a SSAS cube, but I have a connection error.

[image]

The SQL browser service if activated

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it right then you are trying to connect your SSAS tabular cube to SQL Browser in order to query data. In this case -

You can use "Dax Studio" to connect to SSAS tabular cube. Below is the download link:
`https://daxstudio.org/downloads/`

I am not sure if it is possible to connect SSAS tabular cube to SQL Browser. I usually connect it to DAX Studio, Power BI, SSMS and excel analyze and visualize cube data.